# How to access web service using an ordinary java class?

Tags: java, web-services

```
**My Web service class**

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 * @author edward
 *
 */
@WebService
public class HelloWeb {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayGreeting(String name) {
        return "Greeting " + name + "....!";
    }

}
```

---

**My Server java class**

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9090/HelloWeb", new HelloWeb());
        System.out.println("Hello Web service is ready");
    }
}
```

Server is running properly, and i am able to access the service using url that returns WSDL code.But i want to access the server using unique URL in java.I have the following client java code.

**Client to access HelloWeb Service**

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.rpc.Service;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory;

public class WebClient {
    String wsdl = "http://172.21.1.65:9090/HelloWeb?wsdl";
    String namespace = "http://helloweb.com";
    String serviceName = "HelloWebService";

    QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

    {
        try{

        ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
        Service service = serviceFactory.createService(new URL(wsdl), serviceQN);

        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, note that I compiled and ran your server in "test" package, it's important. This is just a basic example to start with JAX-WS.

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class WebClient {

    @WebService(name = "HelloWeb", targetNamespace = "http://test/")
    public interface HelloWeb {
        @WebMethod
        String sayGreeting(String name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Service serv = Service.create(new URL(
                "http://localhost:9090/HelloWeb?wsdl"), 
                new QName("http://test/", "HelloWebService"));
        HelloWeb p = serv.getPort(HelloWeb.class);
        System.out.println(p.sayGreeting("John"));
    }
}
```