# Migrating a CXF client that uses "simple frontend" to JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, cxf, jax-ws, cxf-client

I have a web service client written with Apache CXF, that uses the [simple frontend](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/simple-frontend.html) style. It can dynamically invoke a method on a remote web service, given its location and the interface implemented by the service.

```java
public static void callWsMethod(Class<?> serviceInterface, String address, String methodName,...) {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(serviceInterface);
    factory.setAddress(address);
    Object instance = factory.create();
    ... /*invoke method "methodName" on instance */
```

I want to migrate this code to a pure JAX-WS implementation. My code should look something like:

```java
public static void callWsMethod(Class<?> serviceInterface, String address, String methodName,...) {
    URL wsdlLocation = new URL(address + "?wsdl");
    QName serviceName = new QName( .... , ....); //??? what goes here
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    Object instance = service.getPort(serviceInterface);
    ... /*invoke method "methodName" on instance */
```

I suspect that this is possible because the CXF doc cited above says:

> In a 'simple' case, very nearly identical things happen in the Simple front end as in JAX-WS.

My first problem is the [QName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) constructor:

```
QName(java.lang.String namespaceURI, java.lang.String localPart)
```

how does CXF figure out the right `namespaceURI` and `localPart` to invoke the ws?

Comment: Have you checked this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583918/how-to-access-web-service-using-an-ordinary-java-class

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a WSDL?

```
namespaceUri = /wsdl:definitions/@targetNamespace
localPort = /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/@name
```

If you have a WSDL. Why not simply generate the SEI classes using wsimport? You'll see the generated automatically contains the right QName.